# Align text to the bottom and center in div

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm using the following lines in HTML file with class definitions from bootstrap

```
<div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center" align="bottom">
            <div class="col-2"></div>
            <div class="col-1 bg-white text-black" align="center">aaaaaaaaaaa</div>
            <div class="col-1 bg-white text-black" align="center">bbbbbbbbbbb</div>
            <div class="col-1 bg-white text-black" align="center">ccccccccccc</div>
            <div class="col-1 bg-white text-black" align="center">ddddddddddd, ddddddddddd, dddddddddddd</div>
            <div class="col-1 bg-white text-black" align="center">eeeeeeeeeee</div>
            <div class="col-1 bg-white text-black" align="center">fffffffffff</div>
            <div class="col-1 bg-white text-black" align="center">ggggggggggg</div>
            <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>
```

and what I got is 
[image]

What I really want to have is to align the text in each div to the bottom and vertically in the center. For example, the text "aaaaaaaaaaa" needes to be on the same line as the third line of "ddddddddddd", while it is still in the middle inside its div. Sounds like a easy piece of work, but I still can't figure it out after searching around. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to align items vertically center, you will need to use 'align-items-center' together with 'row'. For more information about bootstrap grid layout, check [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/).

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    ...
</div>
```